# Ubuntu Server 16.04 - Can't login to SSH user even though password is correct

Tags: server, ssh, remote-login

Edit: just so mods don't mark this as duplicate, I have seen pretty much all related questions and none of them have helped me.

Let me just state before beginning that I am relatively new to linux and do not know many commands.

I decided to transform my old laptop into a gaming server with SSH and FTP. The problem is that I am rarely at the same location for a lot of time so I need to access said server with the external IP. Which is where I get the problem.

Whenever I try to login through my internal IP (in this case, 10.0.0.5), I get the following:

```
C:\>ssh minecraft@10.0.0.5
minecraft@10.0.0.5's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-24-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Sat Jun 11 19:16:52 2016 from 10.0.0.12
minecraft@xps-ubuntusrv:~$
```

Which obviously means that the SSH is working. However when I try to access the server through external IP, I get this:

```
C:\>ssh minecraft@yupnotgivingawaymyiplol
minecraft@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
minecraft@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
minecraft@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Keep in mind that all three times I was entering the same passcode as before. This also happens with the default user.

This is my -vvv (keep in mind that I replaced the original IP with 127.0.0.1):

```
C:\>ssh -vvv alex@127.0.0.1
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/MVoloch/.ssh/config
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug2: resolving "127.0.0.1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.52
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:22 as 'alex'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/MVoloch/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file         /home/MVoloch/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 127.0.0.1
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-    v01@openssh.com,rsa-    sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-        nistp256,ecdh-    sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-        exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-    sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-    v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-    ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-    cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-        ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-        cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-    sha2-    256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-        etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-        sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-    sha2-    256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-        etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-        sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-    cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-    cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 495/1024
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa     SHA256:zaEfS0zzZ4DyGf0BjXPPkEi+6puzJs73EkbEm3XSSqU
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/MVoloch/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file         /home/MVoloch/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 127.0.0.1
debug1: Host '127.0.0.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/MVoloch/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 540/1024
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/MVoloch/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or           directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
alex@127.0.0.1's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
alex@127.0.0.1's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
vdebug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
alex@127.0.0.1's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

This is my sshd_config:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Keep in mind that the SSH works completely fine if I connect from the internal IP but as I have to keep changing homes I regularly need to connect from the external IP. Also I am attempting login from a Windows 10 x64 machine with OpenSSH. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my ISP was blocking port 22 all along!

Following Jakuje's tips I looked into the port forwarding. I am now using a virtual server to redirect port `2222` to `22`, so I didn't have to change anything in my configurations, just add a `:2222` at the end of my IP.

Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: This would better serve as a comment on Jakuje's answer, rather than a seperate answer. As you seem to be just verifying the answer that Jakuje suggested.

Comment: I was gonna make it the verified answer but I need to wait one day.. that's why it seems out of place. Don't worry

Comment: Unaccepting my answer, which basically led you to the solution is not the best approach. Your final solution it also important (but it was not possible to derive it from the original question, as it was stated). I agree that my answer as it is now is not comprehensive (the best is when the users find out on their own). @saji89 what do you think is the best approach here?

Comment: @Jakuje If your answer served only as a pointer to the actual answer or its direction, then it seems to be fair enough to unaccept the answer you posted, and create a more comprehensive answer, he could thank you for your effort by upvoting your answer. In the other case, if your answer was complete barring a few minor details, those details can be appended to your answer and the OP can accept it, as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not connecting to your Ubuntu server, but to the router or something else on the network:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52
```

This line should idenitify your server as openSSH, but it says dropbear (usually routers and embedded systems). Once more, check the port forwarding on your router and make sure that you even have public IP to connect.

Comment: That actually might be it as when I log in from the internal IP I get: `debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1`. Any idea how to actually fix the portforwarding problem though? As I stated before, port checker websites state that port 22 is open on my external IP.

Answer (score -3):

OpenSSH may be unreliable. Try using putty to connect. 
[Putty download link](http://putty.org)

Comment: I get this error: `Couldn't agree to a host key algorithm (available: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519)`

Comment: This means that your host has a authentication key. Try to add an authentication key, and put your password on there.

Comment: Yes, I do have one. How do I add it to Putty? OpenSSH worked fine without it..

Comment: On the right, under the connection tab, you should see a key option. You should see a text box at the bottom, and then press the add button.

Comment: Connections > SSH > Kex? If so, that's what I tried to get that error. Still doesn't work.

Comment: When you say key, do you mean password? Of so, then you do not need a key, and you need to remove the key.

Comment: Also, you need to make sure you have forwarded that port. Have you done that?

Comment: `OpenSSH may be unreliable` seams like a very broad and inaccurate statement to make.